# Pass multiple files to elixir program - STDIN

Tags: elixir

I'm doing a little Elixir IO learning and I'm hitting an issue. I want to handle 2 different text files passed in via STDIN.

EXAMPLE:

```
  def run() do
    # IO.inspect IO.read(:stdio, :line)
    case IO.read(:stdio, :line) do
      :eof ->
        :ok
      data ->
        IO.write(:stdio, data)
    end
  end

  Interview.run()
```

I can call this program with `1` file like this:

`elixir program.ex < test.txt`

This works fine. But how do I pass multiple files to this program?

This doesn't work but something like this:

`elixir program.ex < test2.txt test.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
elixir program.ex < test.txt
```

The `<` is unix command line stuff, namely standard input redirection, which has nothing to do with elixir:

> The commands that normally take their input from the standard input
>   can have their input redirected from a file in this manner.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-io-redirections.htm

In elixir, you can get multiple file names from the command line like this:

```
#a.exs:

defmodule My do
  def run do
    System.argv()
    |> Enum.map(fn name -> IO.puts name end)     
  end
end

My.run()
```

Then:

```
~/elixir_programs$ elixir a.exs hello world
hello
world
```

Adding your code gives something like this:

```
defmodule My do
  def run do
    System.argv()
    |> Enum.map(fn name ->     
          {:ok, file} = File.open(name)
          case IO.read(file, :line) do
            :eof ->
              :ok
            data ->
              IO.inspect(data)
          end
    end)
  end
end

My.run()
```

Comment: `Enum.map/2` → `Enum.each/2`. Please do not abuse `map` for simple iteration.